# Do you know how to make a dotted line like this

Tags: ios, swiftui

like this [image: 1]

Do you know how to make a dotted line like this

The width must be full length.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can draw such a line with:

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
        VStack {
            Path{ path in
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: geometry.size.height / 2))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: geometry.size.width, y: geometry.size.height / 2))
            }
            .stroke(style: StrokeStyle( lineWidth: 2, dash: [5]))
            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.blue))
        }
    }
```

This line will be e.g. in the middle of the screen. Just adjust the `y` param to move the line.

The result:

[image: The result]

Comment: how to controll line hight.   this line hight is large

Comment: Just decrease the value of the lineWidth argument.